# Add a InfoBox in the media upload window

Tags: customization, uploads

I am trying to add a InfoBox (just infotext for the user) to the media upload popup window (se mockup link). Any tips on how to adress this feature? Filter hook? Other solution?
Thanks in advance.

[Mockup of InfoBox](http://cl.ly/0q160f3l360E2X1G2k3F)

**Edit**
Problem solved

```
function media_upload_infobox() {?>
<!-- Start infobox -->
<div class="media-infobox" style="background:#ffff99; color:#555555; border: #CCCCCC 1px; border-radius: 10px 10px 10px
    10px; padding:5px;">
    <h4 class="media-infobox-sub-title" style="font-family: Georgia,Times,serif; font-weight: normal; color: rgb(90, 90, 90); font-size: 1.3em; margin: 12px;">Your header here.</h4>
    <p class="media-infobox-infotext" style="margin:12px;"> Infotext here</p>
</div>
<!-- Stop infobox -->

<?php

} // End function media_upload_infobox

// Add function to Action Hook
add_action('pre-flash-upload-ui','media_upload_infobox');
add_action('pre-html-upload-ui','media_upload_infobox');

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to place the message toward the bottom i'd suggest..

```
add_action( 'post-upload-ui', 'upload_window_additions' );
function upload_window_additions() {
    echo '<div>Your content</div>';
}
```

You found a fix whilst i was looking for you, but figured i'd still offer it anyway. :)